# Can I move these items around in active directory

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010, group-policy, organizational-unit

I am just reorganising my companies active directory structure, as it hasn't kept up with changes in the company structure.

There are a few items I am not sure if I can move or not. Can anyone tell if it is ok to move the below or not:

```
Exchange Security Groups OU (Exchange 2010)
Exchange 2010 DiscoverySearchMailbox user account
Exchange 2010 SystemMailbox (x2) user account
Builtin groups found in the Builtin container
All builtin accounts/groups in the default "Users" OU
```

From what I have heard, the Exchange Security Groups OU can be moved in it's entirety as it has a well known GUID and Distinguished name. I am not so sure about the accounts for system mailboxes, although I can't think of any reason why not. All the builtin accounts I assume are fine to move.

Obviously the above statements are only true if they were to be moved to an OU without weird GPOs.

Answer (score 4):

I can't really speak to the Exchange ones, but my attitude would be to leave them as is.  I know you are cleaning up, but typically what I've seen is companies will create a "root OU" for their company in AD, say "ACME" and then place all their objects/OUs/structure *inside* that root OU, leaving the other built in / default AD structure in place and not messing with it.  If they do mess with it for security reasons, they can follow the below Technet article/link.

For the:

> Builtin groups found in the Builtin container

Microsoft recommends that you don't mess with those.  They are protected groups and folders within AD that have specific security checks applied to them periodically.

**See here:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc875827.aspx**

`Groups in the Builtin container cannot be moved to another location.`

However, you **can** move the Administration Accounts and Groups in the `Users` OU into a secure OU, if you follow MS' advice on how to properly do so.

See the section `Strengthening Security on Service Administration Accounts and Groups` in that link for details and walkthroughs.  I would **highly** recommend though before you get started that you detail out your AD structure including GPOs to make sure you don't move something into an OU that will cause you serious problems.  Make sure your backups are up to date and I would even recommend taking simple screenshots of before/after to let you "rollback" if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for that. Ok, there aren't many groups within Builtin, so i'm not overly fused about these. The Users container does have quite a few, so I may look into moving these. I have the rest of our objects sorted in a root OU as you mentioned, then split by type, then sub-company, then location, then department. We currently don't have any GPOs applied other than the default domain policy, so that shouldn't be a concern.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning up and maintaining the AD structure is one thing but don't get wrapped up in "busy work". Organize the OU's and objects that you/the company has created. Leave all of the Built-in and default containers and objects as they are. While there may not be any issue with moving some of these items the fact of the matter is there's just no good reason to do so (or very, very few good reasons to do so).

---

You: "Hmmm... let me just move this here..."

Phone: ring ring ring

You: "Hello"

CEO/CIO/CFO: "The email integration with our ERP/CRM system isn't working anymore. We can't communicate with our customers. We're losing money by the second!"

You: "Oops"

Comment: In terms of the exchange security groups, is it correct that moving them into a managed OU and using GPOs can mean they become more flexible when we start to delegate different permissions to different groups of people? At the moment the company is too small to warrant splitting these roles, but in future it may well be considered.